# cannot acces 'android.app.Activity' which is a supertype of

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, sdk

I have just installed android studio and i'm trying to create my first application. As soon as i create the project i get this error. Obviously i did not write any code and all the lines you see are the default code of the project.

[image]

I tried to sync but, as you see in the terminal below, a license error appears.
How can i fix this problem?
I have installed android studio correctly, installing SDK, tools and so on.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: In Android Studio, try using the *SDK Manager* to download Android API level 29 again. No idea if it will work, but worth giving a shoot.

Comment: where i can find the sdk manager? i'm looking in the tool section but i don't find it.

Comment: For me it's in `Tools` --> `SDK Manager`. I don't know why it wouldn't be there for you. Try re-installing Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the advice of Peppe L-G (the guy who commented my question) i went to sdk manager and in the section "SDK platforms" i installed "Android 10.0(Q)"  (API level 29).
Now everything works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:**

> **File** -> **Sync Project with Gradle Files**

**Option 2:**

> **File** -> **Invalidate Cache & Restart**

Comment: Click file -> Close Project -> Click open an existing project.

try this and tell if doesn't woks.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think when your internet connection was off-line. Because Gradle couldn't reach the library, it thought that was missing.Please check that .when you connected to internet and reopen /reinstalling fix the issue

else check your gradle version android version etc to fix the issue
```

Comment: i'm actually online, even when i'm tryiing to run the code.